# how to take adavantage of hbase+hadoop in the factory which is lack of computer

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i'am new to hbase&hdaoop, recent we want to build Real-time data display application for a factory.
the metadata is collected from other applications that are alreay in use. we should analysis the data do some 
count to make some chart-view for customer.
 but, if the factory doesnot have enough computers to set up hbase+hadoop cluster, and my team want start to learn and use
hbase+hadoop to prepared for future applications through this case.
thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For learning use a single node VM ([1](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Demo+VMs), [2](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/), [3](http://www.mapr.com/products/download)) and for production use a [cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/06/12/amazon-elastic-mapreduce-hbase-mapr/).